# C++/CLI: Public ref struct generates C2011: 'class' type redefinition

Tags: windows, visual-c++, dll, c++-cli

I have a header file in a managed DLL project like so:

Enums.h:

```
#pragma once
...
public ref struct ManagedStruct {
    Bitmap^ image;
}
...
```

This header is referenced both from another class in the DLL and from a separate executable. The managed struct alone is generating:

> error C2011: 'ManagedStruct' : 'class' type redefinition.

If I move the struct to the main header file in the DLL it works fine, and is publicly accessible, so that's what I'm doing, but I would very much like to learn why this is happening when I just move it to another file.

I have checked all necessary includes and namespaces AND tried the obvious header guards, to no avail; I still get the error.

Thanks very much for any insight!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You have to de-tune the traditional C/C++ header file think a bit when you work with managed code.  The principal source of type declarations is the assembly metadata.  This is very different from the native C/C++ compilation model where you *have* to have a header file for types that you make visible to other modules.

I'm going to guess that you get this C2011 error in the EXE project.  Where you both added a reference to the DLL project assembly (like you should) *and* used #include on the header file.  Like you should not.  That's a guaranteed duplicate definition, #pragma once doesn't fix that.

Don't use header files for exported type definitions.  Always use assembly references.

Comment: You are correct—thanks for the information!  Just when I thought I was getting the hang of C++/CLI...

Comment: I was referred here by a closer of my question.  This answer does not tell how to handle the other side of the equation: Within the same DLL, it seems to me Headers are the only way to access a class.  Whether this correct or incorrect (and I'd like to know), this answer doesn't address.

Answer (score 2):

I Know this question is a bit old, but I'm writing this for future usage:
I had the following problem, which was similar:
managed DLL had a managed class.
managed.h:

```
 namespace Managed {    
        ref class CManagedClass {...}
    }
```

in an unamanged class I wanted to use this above class and so in unmanaged.h

```
#include "managed.h"
```

in another DLL I also did:

```
#include "unmanged.h"
```

which resolved in the type redefinition error.
I have found a solution to this issue using the following method:
forward declaration in the unmanaged.h

```
namespace Managed {
    ref class CManagedClass;
}
```

and include the managed.h in the unmanaged.cpp file as usual.

Comment: I had a similar problem, but I wanted the methods in my unmanaged.h to be inlined, and templates. Therefore I could not use your solution with forward declaration and a cpp-file. I had to have the full implementation in my unmanged.h.

I solved my problem by encapsulating #include "managed.h" with an #ifdef:

#ifdef FIRST_DLL_EXPORT 
#include "managed.h" 
#endif 

..and set FIRST_DLL_EXPORT only in the first dll, such that #include "managed.h" would be ignored by any other dll that included `"unmanged.h".