# Referencing a C++/CLI assembly from another C++/CLI assembly

Tags: .net, dll, c++-cli, interop

I am dealing with a multi-product codebase that has two separate C++/CLI projects, both used to Interop between a large unmanaged C++ shared "core" code and WPF and ASP.NET UI front-ends. One is generic and used in every product (let's call it CLI.Interop.Shared), and one product has specific project for highly specialized use that we don't want to clutter the general one with (let's call it CLI.Interop.Product).

The CLI.Interop.Shared contains code relevant to every product (such as marshalling System::String^ to a custom-implemented C++ string, and so on), CLI.Interop.Product has highly specialized code relating the the single product. As far as I'm concerned, this seems like a simple and logical decomposition, but the simplicity ends there.

Currently, we have essentially hacked the CLI.Interop.Shared into the CLI.Interop.Product by adding it as a Project Reference and then actually #including headers from it. This works for pure headers (situations where we might need the marshal_as templates for marshalling), but when we want more inter-operation, this set up does not work with basically anything with an include guard as it will overwrite it as it is a separate assembly, and has shadowing issues with compiled C++/CLI files.

For example, here is where we run into issues, where I am attempting to inherit a product-specific API based on one in CLI.Interop.Shared:

```
#pragma once

#include "./FooAPI.h"

msclr
{
    interop
    {
        product
        {
            foo
            {
                public ref class ProductFooAPI :: public msclr::interop::foo::FooAPI
                {};
            }
         }
     }
}
```

This will generate redefinition issues (C2011) and use of undefined type (C2027) errors, and will not compile. My working theory is that it's just dumping everything from the included files into the new assembly, but then when compared, it will have obvious conflicts. Also, again, this does not appear to be the supported methodology of referencing other C++/CLI assemblies.

I then tried to switch it the "proper" (from what I can gather) way of using #using, and referencing a .obj file (adding the correct directory to the Additional #using Directories). The issue is unresolved and seems similar: I get complaints of the symbol already being imported, as such:

```
Error   14  error C3846: 'FooClass': cannot import symbol from 'c:\checkout\mainrepo\dotnet\libraries\CLI.Interop.Shared\product debug\fooapi.obj': as 'msclr::interop::foo::FooClass' has already been imported from another assembly 'CLI.Interop.Shared'
```

Removing the Project Reference I have set up in the CLI.Interop.Product to CLI.Interop.Shared creates the obvious error of:

```
 error LNK1312: invalid or corrupt file: unable to import assembly  c:\checkout\mainrepo\dotnet\libraries\CLI.Interop.Shared\product debug\CLI.Interop.Shared.lib
```

I've tried directly referencing the DLL (i.e. #using "CLI.Interop.Shared.dll" and #using "CLI.Interop.Shared.lib"), to no avail. I think I've gone about in circles about this in every way possible. Am I missing something? Is there an obvious solution? Is there something I haven't mentioned that will illuminate this at all? I'm tired of using hacked CLI projects!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2978058/17034

Comment: @HansPassant I ran across your previous answer, and I've attempted that removal, but then I get nearly a hundred LNK2001 and LNK2028 errors, where it cannot resolve the external symbols as desired when creating the lib for this CLI project.

Comment: Those a linker errors, not compile errors.  A very different problem, you are not nearly close enough yet to getting those *exact* same linker errors as well with the way you are trying to do it now.  You need to stop trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: @HansPassant I've been getting frustrated and dismissed your methodology too quickly. I went back and implemented your paradigm; I eliminated all out-of-project #includes and #usings and just use namespaces and #include in-assembly files when relevant. I had to add the directory and add the library dependency to the Product CLI, but I am now at the stage where I'm just getting linker errors and everything but this one file seems to work. Thank you, and sorry for being curt.