# "class type redefinition" error when including a .h file from UI proj in a consol app proj in VC++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, console-application, clr, windows

I am programming in VC++ 2010. I have a clr console app proj and a clr win app proj in a solution. I want to send some data from console app to UI form to show in a grid. then I wrote a method in MyForm class and try to use it in console app project. but when I try to include MyForm.h in console app proj, then I get "class type redefinition" error although I have "#pragma once" and #ifdef in my code.

MyForm.h file from Project1 of Solution:

```
#ifndef MYFORM_H
#define MYFORM_H
#pragma once

namespace Project1 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        void AddVal(UInt16 i)
        {
            dataGridView1->Rows[0]->Cells[2]->Value = i;
        }

    protected:
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::DataGridView^  dataGridView1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::DataGridViewComboBoxColumn^  Column1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::DataGridViewTextBoxColumn^  Column2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::DataGridViewTextBoxColumn^  Column3;

    protected: 

    private:
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
...
#pragma endregion
    };

ref class ManagedGlobals {
  public:
  static MyForm ^ p_mf = nullptr;
}; 
#endif
----------------------------
```

source.cpp file from Project1 of Solution:

```
#include "MyForm.h"                    //            The header file of the form
using namespace Project1;            //            The name of the namespace in 

int main(){
    MyForm ^ mf = gcnew MyForm; 
    ManagedGlobals::p_mf = mf;
    mf->ShowDialog();             //            Show the form
    return 0;
}
----------------------------
```

ConsoleApplication.cpp file from ConsoleApplication project of Solution

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "..\project1\MyForm.h"

using namespace System;
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    ...
    ManagedGlobals::p_mf->AddVal(777);
    ...
}
```

Comment: refer
[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977534/c-cli-public-ref-struct-generates-c2011-class-type-redefinition)