# Error C2011 (‘class’ type redefinition) when linking two CLR projects

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli, clr

## The question

I have two CLR projects compiling two DLLs: **Foo** and **Bar**. In these two projects I have defined two classes `FooClass` and `BarClass` (See code below)

The problems is that, when I use `#include “..\Foo\Foo.h”` in my Bar project i get the following error:

> Error C2011: ‘Foo::FooClass’ : ‘class’ type redefinition

How can I solve this?

Thank you very much

## The code

In Foo project (CLR library)

**Foo.h**

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace Foo {

    public ref class FooClass
    {
    };
}
```

**Foo.cpp**

```
#include “Foo.h”
```

In Bar project (CLR library) with a reference to Foo project.

**Bar.h**

```
#pragma once

// Here I include the other class
#include “..\Foo\Foo.h”

using namespace System;

namespace Bar {

    public ref class BarClass
    {
    };
}
```

**Bar.cpp**

```
#include “Bar.h”
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2978058/778374

No need of `#include` in CLR.